# MySQL: Pivot query that I don't understand

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have this OCCUPATIONS table as below and I need to pivot the Occupation column in OCCUPATIONS so that each Name is sorted alphabetically and displayed underneath its corresponding Occupation.
I have a solution but I have some questions.
I tried searching and asked chatGPT for explanation but I still got confused. Please help me exlain this machanism.

1. How the combination of MAX(or MIN) and CASE can achieve the transformation of rows into columns?
2. Why does it need to be used with GROUP BY RowNumer to yield the full list? (if omited, each column will only have 1 Name with the highest value in RowNumber)

Here's the challenge link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/occupations/problem?isFullScreen=true

Here's the solution:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Doctor' THEN Name END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Professor' THEN Name END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Singer' THEN Name END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Actor' THEN Name END)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Name, 
        Occupation, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Occupation ORDER BY Name) AS RowNumber
    FROM OCCUPATIONS
    ) AS NewTable
GROUP BY RowNumber;
```

[image: Table]